# captcha validation not matching

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have created captcha validation in my form. every thing is working.but validation cannot be done to pass through next screen

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('regno', 'regno','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'dob','required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Security Code', 'trim|required|checkcaptcha');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
        echo "test";

    }
    else
    {
```

only first condition is checked. I want to be move out else condition.

```
public  function checkcaptcha()
{   
    if ($_SESSION["code"] == $this->input->post('captcha')) {
        $json['success']  = true;
    } else {
        $json['error']  = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);

}

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE && ($_SESSION["code"] == $this->input->post('captcha')))
```

I made this now it's working. is it correct

Comment: first it should be `callback_checkcaptcha` and second there should be a method named `checkcaptcha` in your controller to check validation

Comment: $this->form_validation
        ->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'callback_checkcaptcha'); is it correct

Comment: yes , create a method also for that see docs https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: i added checkcaptcha validation function. find out any error

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*It should be like this :*

```
public  function checkcaptcha($str)
{   
    if ($_SESSION["code"] == $str ) 
    {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkcaptcha', 'The {field} is invalid');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

*And don't forget to `echo validation_errors()` method in your form to see the errors if any*

Pls read  : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods